# NullPointerException in fragment's onResume

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment in main activity that handle all action on my activity.

rarely NullPointerException occurs , when I use fragment properties:

fragment code:

```
    public class ProjectInfoFragment extends Fragment {
        private static final String ARG_PID = "pid";
        private int projectId;
        View view;
        public ProjectInfoFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        public static ProjectInfoFragment newInstance(int pid) {
            ProjectInfoFragment fragment = new ProjectInfoFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_PID, pid);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (getArguments() != null) {
                projectId = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PID);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            mainAction();
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup  container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_project_info, container, false);
            return view;
        }

        private void mainAction() {
            ProjectModel projectModel = new ProjectModel(getContext());
            if (!projectModel.findByKey(projectId + "")) { //// line 121
            //!!!!!!! here NullPointerException occurs !!!!!!
                return;
            }
        }   

    }
```

Important note: I doing many things in mainAction() that must done in onResume() and I can't do this in createView or other functions.

logs:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method boolean ir.rabint.shahta.model.ProjectModel.findByKey(java.lang.String) on a null object referencen
    at ir.rabint.shahta.activity.fragment.ProjectInfoFragment.mainAction(ProjectInfoFragment.java:121)
    at ir.rabint.shahta.activity.fragment.ProjectInfoFragment.onResume(ProjectInfoFragment.java:92)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2238)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1346)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.uteOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.uteOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.uteOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAnduteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.PendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

Comment: Can you attach the log? It seems unlikely that you have a null pointer exception because of projectId as it is a primitive type.

Comment: can u attach the log?

Comment: Attach log and projectId cannot be null as it will be initialized to 0 initially. Its a primitive type

Comment: ideltify value for projectId is passing correct from bundle where you are passing and follow variable initialization to some value by default. you can assign value for projectId = 0 where declared.

Comment: `projectModel.findByKey(projectId + "")` returns null

Comment: mayby projectModel is null! , my code is very simple and findByKey can't return null... ,

Comment: Is it possible that new ProjectModel(getContext()); return null?

Answer (score 0):

The `!` operator works only with `Boolean` data types/methods. Here you are comparing a String as stated in stack trace. 
So do the following

```
if(projectModel != null){
    if(!projectModel.findByKey(projectId + "").equals("")){
    return;
    }
}else{
//do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: I think changing it to `if (projectModel.findByKey(projectId + "") == null)` would be easier. Your code still would throw a NPE because you're trying to call `equals` on `null`.

Comment: Still would throw a NPE :P the problem in his code is that `projectModel.findByKey(projectId + "")` returns `null`, so you cannot call `equals`on it.

Comment: Oh, yea makes sense. I don't think we can help him with that, unless he'll show us the complete code.